# How to mount docker volumes to a folder on a network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have docker installed on windows with a gitlab container running. Currently, I am mounting volumes to C drive but I want to mount the volumes to a folder on my network which is a server. My `docker-compose` file looks like this:

```
version: "3.6" 
services:
  web:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce'
    container_name: 'gitlab'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'localhost'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'http://localhost:9090'
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2224
    networks:
      - gitlab-network
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '9090:9090'
      - '2224:22'
    volumes:
      - 'C:\GitlabConfig:/etc/gitlab'
      - 'gitlab-logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - 'gitlab-data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

If whenever I want to create a backup then the backup should be stored in the folder on the network path. I want to store the backup on this path: `\\power\Benutzer\hgul\GitlabConfig`. Anyone has any idea if it is possible like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to mount the network volumes on your system as local disks (or folder in a local disk) and then change your configuration to write on them.

One of the possible ways to achieve a similar result is adapting and using this command:

```
mklink /d "C:\GitlabConfig" "\\power\Benutzer\hgul\GitlabConfig"
```

Then your config will look like this:

```
volumes:
  - 'C:\GitlabConfig:/etc/gitlab'
```

**Bonus**

More solutions about mounting the network drive:
https://superuser.com/questions/244562/how-do-i-mount-a-network-drive-to-a-folder

Comment: But the backup I have is in the C:\GitlabConfig. Will this command copies the data to the folder on the network or it is the other way around?

Comment: This command will just mount the network folder to your c:
If you copy a file to the right folder in c: you will find it in your network share
Test it, it is easier done than said :)

Comment: But it will create a symbolic link which I don't want. I want to have the backup at the network drive, not a link which points to another directory.

Comment: You will backup to the network drive using this.
Did you test it? Your c:\whatever will basically be your network drive. I've updated my answer using your names, I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Also possible: I didn't get your requirements right.
What do you want to do? Mount your docker folders in network shares or perform backups of your docker folders in network shares? The subject of your question: "How to mount docker volumes to a folder on a network" seems very clear but now I start having doubts.

Comment: As of now, my docker backups are created in the folder C:\GitlabConfig. I want to change my configurations so that the backups are created on the network drive directly not in the C:\GitlabConfig directory.

Comment: I have edited my solution in order to match your request @thenrun

Comment: Hi @thenrun, if my answer was useful for you please consider upvoting it and/or choosing it as final answer. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to work.